# PHP: how to log all file changes to detect vulnerabilities in multi-hosting website?

Tags: php, linux, apache, security

I have an apache2 + php server, using Debian GNU/Linux, with some virtual hosts.
I usually find modified files written by the web server (www-data) containing
@include("path_to_unwanted_files")
and new files introduced through some vulnerabilities (maybe joomla, wordpress, I don't know).

Is it possible to configure php to write a log with script name and filesystem write operation, to know which script is modifying/adding files?

Any suggestion to prevent this problem is welcome.

With the command
`egrep -r '@include[ ]*\(".*/.*\..*");' *`
I find many php files including other files:

> /*10974*/
>
> @include ("PATH/import/.2112ebb1.otc");
>
> /*10974*/

Comment: If attackers can modify your files, you should worry about something else than figuring out individual include statements. They typically can modify _a lot_ more than this single line. Consider your server compromised and start with a known-clean-deployment.